# How can I pass in `app` so I can make endpoints in the model.js file?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm a node.js noob. I want to be able to create endpoints from my model files. I'm thinking if I can pass in `app` I can just add the endpoints straight from there. I'm using Sequelize. One of my models looks something like this:

```
const user = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
       id: {
           type: DataTypes.STRING,
           primaryKey: true,
           unique: true
       },
       name: {
           type: DataTypes.STRING,
       },
       email: {
           type: DataTypes.STRING,
       },
   });


   return User;
};

module.exports = user;
```

I create `app` with `var app = express();` in a different file `server.js`.

```
  const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

  const sequelize = new Sequelize('carswaddle', 'kylekendall', 'password', {
    dialect: 'postgres',
  });

  const models = {
    User: sequelize.import('./user'),
    Service: sequelize.import('./service'),
  };

  Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
    if ('associate' in models[key]) {
      models[key].associate(models);
    }
  });

  models.sequelize = sequelize;
  models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

  module.exports = models;
```

Is how I use Sequelize.

P.S Any suggestions about my code would be very welcomed..

Comment: Defining routes in models is not the best practice and It violates the boundary of MVP.

Comment: You should always separate your models and controllers

Comment: Nice, okay, so is it normal to make a route file for a model? I'm really looking for best practices, I haven't seen much when searching for file system setup. Could you provide an example of where you put the different files and what a file with routes looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this blog to get started with best practices and File structure

Your entry point of the app should be defined like this

```
// This will be our application entry. We'll setup our server here.
const http = require('http');
const app = require('../app'); // The express app we just created

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8000;
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

In this only you are starting an express server.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize

and your folder structures for the app should be looking like this you can customize it as per your convenience but it should be similar to this

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
└── server
    ├── config
    │   └── config.json
    ├── migrations
    ├── models
    │   └── index.js
    └── seeders
```

now you models folder will contain all database models for you. 
and you should mount all your routes in app.js file. here is sample code snippet for mounting your routes

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Require our routes into the application.
require('./server/routes')(app);
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
  message: 'Welcome to the beginning of nothingness.',
}));

module.exports = app;
```

Where your routes folder will be something like this or you can define nested folder structure for this also bypassing express router to from bottom to up.

and to write controllers you should import models in the controller.

you can create sample todo object like this. we are exporting create to use in routes.

```
const Todo = require('../models').Todo;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .create({
        title: req.body.title,
      })
      .then(todo => res.status(201).send(todo))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```